# jQuery UI sortable and tinyMCE

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using tinyMCE WYSIWYG's on a slideshow editing page and I want to use jQuery UI to make them sortable as well. The markup looks like this:

```
<div class="slide-content">
    ...
    <textarea id="Slide_0_content"></textarea>
    <textarea id="Slide_1_content"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the code that kicks off jQuery sortable:

```
$('#slide-list').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui){
        $('.slide-content textarea').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
        });
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $('.slide-content textarea').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
        });
    }
});
```

When I drop a slide, the content area for that slide goes blank and I can't even click inside it to type more. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with an example of your problem

Answer (score -2):

Here is what worked for me, on start I just trigger save with tinyMCE.triggerSave(); and on stop I start tinyMCE again.

```
$("#sort").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    items: "div.tiny",
    start: function(event, ui) { 
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        startTiny();
    }
});
function startTiny(){
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        width : "100%",
        height: "100",
        mode : "textareas"
    });
}
startTiny();
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YfUyM/3/